# Angular 4 how to restrict creation of components

Tags: angular

Code of example

```
<p-accordion *ngIf="cat" (onOpen)="openTabAccordion($event)" [ngClass]="{'p-accordion':true}">
  <p-accordionTab *ngFor="let item of cat;let i = index"  [header]="item.data.name">
    <div *ngIf="results; else loading">
        <p-listbox  *ngIf="results.length > 0; else not_data" [style]="{'width':'100%','max-height':'250px'}"
            [options]="results"
            [(ngModel)]="currentP" (onChange)="selectedP($event);">
            <ng-template let-p pTemplate="item">
                <app-p-i [prop]="p.value"></app-p-i>
            </ng-template>
        </p-listbox>
        <ng-template #not_data>
            Not Record Found
        </ng-template>
    </div>
    <ng-template #loading>loading ...</ng-template>
  </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

The component  app-p-i I want that it only invoke in the current accordionTab but when debug the app-p-i, it creates many instance how accordionTab has the p-accordion.

How to restrict creation of component to only open accordionTab, it's possible or I have define every accordionTab explicit

Comment: Long story short, you would have to involve some kind of logic that links the currently selected tab with the content you want to show getting a reference of which tab was clicked (index) and the `let i = index` variable you're saving. So you only show the results tab that meets the condition, let's say `selectedTabIndex === i`.

Comment: Thank you very much